# How to exclude files from clang analyzer?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I run clang analyzer with

```
clang++ --analyze --analyzer-output html ...
```

It works great and integrated into my CMake seamlessly. Now I want to exclude third-parties from the analysis. `scan-build --help` tells me this is done with `--exclude` option. So I try adding it:

```
clang++ --analyze --analyzer-output html -Xanalyzer --exclude -Xanalyzer /path/to/thirdparty ...
```

But clang tells me:

> error: unknown argument: '--exclude'

It seems like clang expects different arguments than `scan-build`. But what is the proper option to pass? And where can I see the complete list?

Comment: Try the similar flag usage that passes flags to the linker: -Wl,-rpath,$(CLANG_INSTALL_DIR)/lib. So: -Xanalyzer,--exclude,/path/to/thirdparty or slight variations thereof.